# One-hot encoding in R- creating dataframe column names from variables in a loop

Tags: r, one-hot-encoding

I am using a dataframe called "rawData" which has a column called "Season" with values ranging from 1 to 4.
I am trying to use a loop to perform one-hot-encoding, i.e create 4 new columns called "Season 1" , "Season 2", "Season 3", "Season 4", where each column has a binary indicator value of 1/0 showing whether the Season in the column name is occurring for each data-point. So far I have tried this:

```
for (i in 1:4){
text<-paste("Season", toString(i), sep = " ")
if (rawData$season==i) {
rawData$text<-1
}
}
```

However, I am just getting an additional column in my dataframe called "text" with all values =1. I understand why R is doing this, but I can not figure out an alternative way to make it do what I want. I tried changing the if-then statement to change "rawData$text" to "rawData$paste("Season", toString(i), sep = " ")<-1" but that is giving me an error

Comment: Please add a reproducible example along with expected output.

Comment: you dont need a for loop to do one hot encoding, kindly provide us reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(
  group = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C'),
  student = c('01', '01', '01', '02', '02', '01', '02'),
  exam_pass = c('Y', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'N'),
  subject = c('Math', 'Science', 'Japanese', 'Math', 'Science', 'Japanese', 'Math')
)

library(dummy)
library(dummies)

df1 <- dummy.data.frame(df, names=c("subject"), sep="_")
```

This reproducible sample code will help you to do one hot encoding without using for loop.

Example provided by you also works for the same

```
df1 <- data.frame(seasons = c(1,3,2,4,3,4,1,1,1))

library(dummy)
library(dummies)

df2 <- dummy.data.frame(df1, names=c("seasons"), sep="_")
```

Comment: When I tried doing this I get the following error message:
"Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?"

It is probably because my datagrame column "seasons" has numeric values as opposed to strings like you seem to. Do you know what I can change to fix this?  Thank you

Comment: have a look at the updated answer i have added your seasons data. Code is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Someone else just showed me how to do it:

```
df <- data.frame(seasons = c(1,3,2,4,3,4,1,1,1))
for(i in unique(df$seasons)) {
  df[[paste0("season_",i)]] <- ifelse(df$seasons==i,1,0)
}
```